# Build pybind11 project on visual studio without cmake (Windows)

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio, pybind11

I'm trying to setup a PyBind11 project on Visual Studio without using CMake on Windows platform. I followed the instructions on the following link:

[Create a C++ extension for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

I have *pybind11* installed via *vcpkg* and also *Python3.9 x86/x64*, *Visual Studio 2019 Professional* installed separately. But for my pybind11 project, I'm using x64 architecture. I have successfully executed **Create the core C++ projects** and **Convert the C++ projects to extensions for Python** with **Use PyBind11** as given in the link. I am in the process of **Make the DLL available to Python** in which I'm using the 2nd approach.

I have created the *setup.py* & *pyproject.toml* file. For building the extension, the step 5 is: **In Solution Explorer, right-click the active Python environment, and then select Manage Python Packages.**. However, I can't find *active Python environment* in the *Solution Explorer* of Visual Studio. The following screenshot illustrates that (I'm trying to expose the C++ functions written in *main2.cpp* to Python).

[VisualStudio_SolutionExplorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKQxV.png)

I tried adding the Python3.9 x64 environment to Visual Studio 2019 using their *Add Environment* feature and it seems to appear in *C:\Users\#####\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\env*. But despite of that, I don't have active Python environment in Solution Explorer. So how to build the pyproject.toml file ?